# UIImageView on Rotating moves its center

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder, cgaffinetransform, uianimation

I am trying to rotate an UIImageView periodically using  **CGAffineTranformationMakeRotation()** function.....

***Following is the code....***

```
       - (void)showSpinnerAnimation
       {
               rotateAngle += 3.14f;

              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.18 animations:^{
                      self.spinnerImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotateAngle); 
              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      [self showSpinnerAnimation];
              }];
       }
```

But what i am observing is

`Along with the rotating UIImageView. It is also shifting from its center.`

*I tried with previous SO Questions regarding this problem and thereby i tried the following methods*

```
1. Set the center of the UIImageView in the completion code (by copying the center in a CGPoint variable).
2. Tried with setting autolayout. But it will break other constraints which i already set for other UI elements in IB.
```

*Please note that the self.spinnerImageView is an IBOutlet UIImageView reffered from IB.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
- (void) rotateView:(UIView *)theView
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue =[NSNumber numberWithFloat: -M_PI];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.7;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    [theView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

And to stop rotating remove the animation from the layer

```
-(void)stopRotating:(UIView *)theView
{
    [theView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
    // or
    //[theView.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

Pass your UIImageView to the method.

```
[self rotateView:self.spinnerImageView]
```